# transfer data between as400 and Oracle

Tags: jdbc, oracle11g, ibm-midrange, data-migration

I need to transfer huge amount of data from AS400 to Oracle db.
I think to write a java code but I have not developed java for a long time.
I think I need to use AS400 and Oracle jdbc drivers at the same time.

Can I write a statement like this:

INSERT INTO ORACLE_DB.TABLE_TARGET
SELECT * FROM AS400.TABLE_SOURCE

Comment: What happens if you try it?

Comment: I do not have Java editor on my computer. Unfortunately installing softwares can last at least 2-3 days. So if using java code is not working or it is too slow; I will try to look for other possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

Both databases need different JDBC drivers ... so I don't think you'll be able to easily to an insert on a select.

You will probably have to write a program to do the data transfer.  Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6397342/connecting-to-multiple-databases-using-different-jdbc-drivers) post for information on using two jdbc drivers.